# Sagepay 3D Secure redirecting to acs url returns a blank page

Tags: opayo, 3d-secure

Redirecting to the below url (with CRM webform step )is returning a blank page. Any solutions?

Thanks in Advance

https://test.sagepay.com/mpitools/accesscontroler?action=eJxVUttuwjAMfd9XVHxA04ReKDJBBbStmtiqMW17jVKPVusF0naUv18CZYw8+Rw7J/ZxYN6XhfWDqsnrajaitjOa8zt4yxTiaoOyU8hhjU0jtmjl6WzEHOr5rkvHzJ14XkiZx8YjDkn0insOgxDXOjYFcoFaQclMVC0HIfeL+Jm7IQsdB8gAoUQVr3jgMjcMqDMcIGcaKlEiXwqFy7qrZF581epDFNgAOWVAarpVRz5hPpALgE4VPGvb3ZSQw+FgS3kwd+xabe3uG4hJA7l2lnQmarRcn6c88WV9T/1sUX0+Rfu+E+OXh/6dreNFNANiKiAVLXLtR+gELLSoP6Xu1JkAOfEgStMH95zgNOcZwc48Et2k/lOgDVdYycsoFwTY7+oKdQUD8hdDio3kG7OaRBytdRLrxw0F5DrM8tGYLlvtIzV+nyKjl2uPdPdnQQOAmFoyrJIMW9fRzW/4BYe1tvY=

Expected: 3D Secure page of the respective bank should be loaded

Answer (score 0):

You need to be automatically POSTing a form - not have URL variables.

```
    `<form name="form" id="3dsecureform" action="https://test.sagepay.com/mpitools/accesscontroler?action=pareq" method="post"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="MD" value="[MD]" />
   <input type="hidden" name="PaReq" value="[PaReq]" />
   <input type="hidden" name="TermUrl" value="[TermUrl]" />
   <button type="submit btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>`
```